# XSL test if self-closed element is met in for-each loop

Tags: xslt, if-statement, foreach

Here's xml example:

```
<a>
    <b>Text</b>
    <b>Text</b>
    <b>Text</b>
    <page/>
    <b>Text</b>
    <b>Text</b>
    <page/>
    <b>Text</b>
    <b>Text</b>
    <b>Text</b>
    <b>Text</b>
</a>
```

And here is html I want to achieve:

```
<p>Text Text Text</p>
<p>Text Text</p>
<p>Text Text Text Text</p>
```

It's first time I'm using XSL so please, forgive me.

Right now I'm using this loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="a/*">
    <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="UNKNOWN_TEST">
    </p>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My question is, what do I need to type instead of UNKNOWN_TEST here? Or maybe that's not they way I should try to work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see if it's self-closed, you can test if it's empty, it won't work anyway, because your `xsl` is not well-formed.

Possible (not really pleasing) solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/a/b[name(preceding-sibling::*[1])!='b']">
   <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pp" select="generate-id(preceding-sibling::page[1])" />
    <xsl:variable name="fp" select="generate-id(following-sibling::page[1])" />
    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::b[generate-id(preceding-sibling::page[1])=$pp and generate-id(following-sibling::page[1])=$fp]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',./text())"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </p>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that I open `p` tag with every `b` element. Could You tell me how should I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do. You may, for instance, for each `b` that has no preceding `b` select all consecutive `b`s. or `b`s that have no `page` in between...

Comment: Every `b` is line of text from a book. Every `<page/>` means that one page ended and next starts. So I want to have every "page" (`b`s between `<page/>`s) wrapped inside `<p>`. I hope this explains it a little bit. Sorry for my awful English.

Comment: Umm... it's somewhat tricky, I'll try to come up with some awkward solution for you... I doubt it's perfect, but that's what comes to my mind, hang on, I'll edit it into answer.

Comment: Thank You Michael. I'll read your answer and @lwburk answer, then I'll accept if I won't have any other questions. Right now its pretty complicated to me...

Comment: It works very well except one thing. It freezes my browser for a few seconds (there is a lot of text). But maybe I will be able to type something similar myself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake to think of XSLT as processing the literal text of the document. It's working on a model, a representation, one in which `<page/>` and `<page></page>` are equivalent. However, you made the following comment on a previous answer:

> Every `b` is line of text from a book. Every `<page/>` means that one
>   page ended and next starts. So I want to have every "page" (`b`s
>   between `<page/>`s) wrapped inside `<p>`. I hope this explains it a
>   little bit.

The following stylesheet uses a `key` to group `b` elements by their preceding `page`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byPage" match="b" 
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::page[1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- handle the first group of b's with no preceding page -->
            <p><xsl:apply-templates select="key('byPage', '')"/></p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|page"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="page">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates select="key('byPage', generate-id())"/></p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following output is produced:

```
<a>
   <p>
      <b>Text</b>
      <b>Text</b>
      <b>Text</b>
   </p>
   <p>
      <b>Text</b>
      <b>Text</b>
   </p>
   <p>
      <b>Text</b>
      <b>Text</b>
      <b>Text</b>
      <b>Text</b>
   </p>
</a>
```